# SQL Server is padding string variables

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, padding

When I run this

```
declare @short nchar(1) = '1';
declare @long nchar(5) = '123456';

select 'A' + CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN @short ELSE @long END + 'B'
```

I get the result

```
-------
A1    B
```

SQL Server seems to be padding the result of the CASE construct up the longest possible return value. This only happens when I use variables, not with constants.

Oddly enough, when I explicitly trim the variable, the result is correct, i.e.

```
select 'A' + CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN rtrim(@short) ELSE @long END + 'B'
```

returns

```
----
A1B
```

Is this behavior by design, and can it be turned off through a server setting?

Comment: Does not happen with Varchar either, btw, just with char types. Apparently the CASE construct is treated like a char type with the longest possible length. So I suppose it is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `CASE` expression, data type precedence takes over. All of the expressions in the branches will be converted to a compatible data type. In this case, it needs to be `NCHAR(5)` so that it can fit either `@short` or `@long`. You can affect the output after that, as you have demonstrated, using functions. Or you can ensure that all of the data types for each possible output or the same. Or use a datatype that doesn't incur padding (`nvarchar` instead of `nchar`).